# Is good practice to have lot of entities (like 1500 or more) in memory?

Tags: java, jpa

i have a JPA Entity (EclipseLink) developing a web application with JSF 2. Let's say i have this:

```
private String table;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "NodeTypeID")
    private Collection<NodeEntity> nodeEntityCollection;
```

That collection is coming very large because, of course, the rows in the table at the database are a lot. I don't show all those entities in the web because... you can't do it, is too much for a web page. So i limit the collection to 150 objects.

I limit it after the +1,000 entities are already on memory, so i guess the process of making all those instances has to be slow. So, i just want to know, what would you do in this case ? Just make a query to bring just the 150 entities i want ? Is there an annotation for that ? Is it good practice to let that process just like that ?

Comment: JPA **is not** Entity Framework from .Net

Comment: 1500 doesn't sound very many, how big are these objects?

Comment: Pagination, filtering, caching, etc.

Comment: The obvious answer is that it's not "right" to bring all 1,500 objects into memory if you're not going to use them.

However, whether it hurts performance can only be answered by you, for your application and its requirements.  You might consider it relatively harmless.

Consider logging out some timings to see what the cost is, and/or use a profiler.  Even if you leave the inefficient code in, then at least you'll know what the cost is.

Comment: One million entries is likely to be slower. If 1500 is slow, use a better library.

Answer (score 0):

In hibernate Criteria there are couple of methods to handle pagination, ie retrieve 150 rows at a time, the client has to keep track of page number that you are viewing and send it to the server. Storing 1500 rows in  the server is usually not a big deal for short duration.

```
 setFirstResult(i*PAGE_SIZE)
 setMaxResults(PAGE_SIZE)
```

ref : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/envers/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setMaxResults(int)